# HTML's Selection object returning the wrong node

Tags: javascript, html, selection

It's important for me to know the difference between clicking before one letter versus after the previous, even though both cases might look the same on screen. This is because the meaning can be carried through the number of spans that are nested. An example:

```html
<span id="x-container"><span id="x">x</span></span><span id="y">y</span>

<script>
  document.addEventListener('selectionchange', e => {
    var selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.type =='Caret')
      console.log(selection.anchorNode.textContent,selection.anchorOffset)
  })
</script>
```

The console.log()s look as follows:

clicking on the x slightly left-of-center, we get x 0 (correct)

clicking on the x slightly right-of-center, we get x 1 (correct)

clicking on the y slightly left-of-center, we get x 1 again: WRONG!!!!

clicking on the y slightly right-of-center, we get y 1 (correct)

How can I fix this third case so I can tell whether we clicked before y versus after x? I tried adding a dummy span between the two but it didn't work.

Note that the x and y look a little close to each other here. In the actual thing I'm doing, I'm adding padding so it doesn't look as strange and is easier to click before y vs after x. Just take my word for it that adding padding/margin doesn't change the problem...

Comment: Firefox exposes the behavior you'd expect (clicking on "x" towards the right sets it as the anchor with offset 1, while clicking on "b" towards the left sets it as the anchor with offset 0). Not sure what Chrome is doing here...

Comment: Do you only need to handle the selection through click case? If so, simply listen for the mouse event that happened right before the selectionchange.

Comment: Yeah chrome is being weird.... how does mouseEvent let you access what I want?

Comment: Here's the updated question with code snippet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879724/javascript-selection-object-is-not-giving-the-correct-anchornode

Comment: **Iff** you are only interested in the selectionchange that gets triggered by mouse events (and not by other means like keyboard or other AT things), then we can check which element received that mouse event, and we can retrieve the correct offset: https://jsfiddle.net/ex4d35kf/ But that's only IFF you are only interested in click triggered selectionchange, so please answer my question.

Comment: Yes I am only interested in mouse events!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only interested in the selectionchange events that were triggered by a mouse event, you can check which element received the mousedown event that did trigger this selectionchange event.
You just have to store it in a variable accessible to your selectionchange handler, then if it's not the Selection's `anchorNode`, or doesn't contain it, you know that the browser messed up.
You then have to check if the actual target was before or after to correctly find the new `anchorOffset`:

```js
let activeElem = null;
document.addEventListener('selectionchange', e => {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  let { anchorNode, anchorOffset } = selection;
  if (anchorNode === selection.focusNode) {
    if (activeElem && (!activeElem.contains(anchorNode))) {
      const isBefore = activeElem.nextElementSibling.contains(anchorNode);
      anchorOffset = isBefore ? activeElem.textContent.length : 0;
      anchorNode = activeElem;
    }
    console.log(anchorNode.textContent, anchorOffset);
  }
})
document.addEventListener("mousedown", e =>
  // here you can change the selector from "span" to anything more restrictive
  // as long as it matches your "targetted" elements
  activeElem = e.target.matches("span") ? e.target : null
);
document.addEventListener("mouseup", e => activeElem = null);
```

```html
<span id="x">x</span><span id="b">b</span>
```

Comment: I might add that selectionchange doesn't change between clicking x1 and b0 like it does for the other changes. No problem though, I can just clear the range. This is a working solution and I thank you for that!

Comment: Yes that's expected. It's because for the browser the Selection didn't change. If you need that you'd need to update it yourself, though you may get a new event, so you may have to temporarily disable it.